# when is it (un)necessary to add -ing

Tags: word-usage, word-request, difference

Sometimes I get confused if I should add -ing or not. For example, is 'view history' or 'viewing history' correct? or are both technically correct? In general what part of language does this question concern so I can learn more about it?

Comment: Please give us some contexts that you see or use these phrases in.

Comment: This article may help you find the right terms to learn more about -ing forms: [Definition and Examples of -ing Forms in Grammar](https://www.thoughtco.com/ing-form-in-grammar-1691171) There are a lot of rules that depend on whether you're asking about present participles, gerunds, or verbs, so unfortunately I think this particular question is too broad to be answered well. If you find some examples that you have questions about, you should ask specifically about those as Eddie indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Both "view history" and "viewing history" are valid phrases, but they have different grammatical functions.  As a general rule<sup>1</sup> using "-ing" will allow you to treat the verb as a noun.  Remember English is an SVO/SVOO language.  S and O (and O) need to be nouns, but "view" is a verb (V).

So we can have:

> **S**   **V**       **O**
> I view history.

Now the gerund lets us take the verb "view" and turn it into a noun, so that it can be the object to a different verb, such as "like".

> **S**  **V**       **O**         **O**
> I like viewing history.

I hope this helps.

<sup>1.  There are exceptions and other uses for gerunds, but this is the most common use and should help your English study quite a bit.</sup>

Comment: but what about 'view history' as a noun? like someone's 'view history' on netflix. would that be grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No.  In that case, "history" is the noun, and "view" is an adjective.  You would need an article or other determiner.  "This is my view history" for example.

Comment: i'm confused how viewing can be a noun without a "the". in 'i like viewing history' how is viewing a noun and not either a verb or modifier of history?

Comment: It's not a "concrete noun".  It's... it's a gerund.  A gerund allows us to treat a verb as if it were a noun, grammatically.  In other words, it allows us to perform a verb with another verb as the object.  Let's drop "viewing" for the moment, and change to "swim / swimming".  You can't say "I like swim", because that's two verbs in one sentence.  But we can say "I like swimming."  The -ing allows "swim" to be the object of "like".

Answer (score 0):

Try studying English verb forms. Probably every English verb can appear as the bare form or as a gerund (-ing) form. In this case, the object *history* doesn't limit the possibilities at all.